# How to make robocode on linux read .net robots (dll files)

Tags: linux, .net-framework

I'm trying to run [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) on ubuntu linux. Normal java version works fine, but I can't force it to read dll files containing robots written in C# (see [.net plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/robocode/files/robocode/1.7.2.1/robocode.dotnet-1.7.2.1-setup.jar/download))

After installing .net plugin I tried to run robocode like that:

```
java -Xmx512M -Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false -cp libs/robocode.jar;libs/jni4net.j-0.7.1.0.jar robocode.Robocode $*
```

But it seems it is not working - the robocode runs, but still doesn't read the robots from dll files.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might need a .NET runtime such as `mono`.

Comment: I have it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Robocode is using [jni4net](http://jni4net.sf.net) as bridge to .NET. jni4net doesn't support unixes/mono yet.
More in this [thread](http://groups.google.com/group/jni4net/browse_thread/thread/491e33083fd63a31/75a9806d60f57e07?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=mono#75a9806d60f57e07)

Comment: Did this change in the past two years?